# how to create a button in WebOS?

Tags: webos, mojo

I am trying to start my development in WebOS. I just started with a simple application with a label and a button. Here's the code snippet:

```
<div class="palm-body-text">

    <div id="main" class="palm-hasheader"> 

     <div class="palm-header">First Scene</div>  
     <div class="palm-text">Welcome to my World</div>  
     <div class="myButton" x-mojo-element="Button"></div>  

    </div> 
</div>
```

In emulator it's not showing up the button. Also its giving a warning on button line which says

```
unknown attribute x-mojo-element.
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: please take a bit more care editing your questions. To highlight code or xml, just select the whole block and click on the `{}` button in the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to setup the button in the scene assistant first.  The button is only rendered after you call `this.controller.setupWidget` in the scene assistant's `setup` function.  Until you do that it's just a `div` without any special meaning.